# Maximum length of string that can be stored in string property of green dao

Tags: java, android, greendao

I have to store similar data in green dao for many ids. So i decided to concatenate all the ids into one string and then store in the  green dao as one row. As i can extract the data using like query.

As the ID string will be quite long, so i was wondering how many characters long string can be stored in string property of green dao.

And i also wanted to ask whether it is a good approach or not.

Thanks.

Comment: *i also wanted to ask whether it is a good approach or not* from a design perspective, I would say no. From an optimization perspective, maybe

Comment: @TimCastelijns can you recommend me any other approach?

Comment: maybe put the data that is the same for many rows in a separate table and link them by their id. I'm not a database designer though, my idea may be even worse

Answer (score 1):

I am storing very long strings, however I can advise that this is a really bad approach, because using the query builder, you can not specify which columns to load on a `dataDao.loadAll();`, which ends up causing this error, as you don't have enough memory.

> CursorWindow  W  Window is full: requested allocation 250689 bytes,
>   free space 175628 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes greenDAO  D  Window
>   vs. result size: 12/22

Using lazylists did not help me, I think you should partition the data into another table, add a relationship, and then you can do something like `data.getMyStringBlob`, as Tim Castelijns suggested above. When you actually need that data.